# iOS Kobold Kit how to disable on-screen debug (gpu: renderer: ...etc)?

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, sprite-kit, kobold-kit

When a vanilla Sprite Kit project is started, it shows node count and FPS using these calls

```
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
```

However, I cannot seem to disable these for KKView, I tried:

```
self.kkView.showsFPS = NO;
self.kkView.showsNodeCount = NO;
self.kkView.showsDrawCount = NO;
```

and I still get blue debug text in the lower right corner.

**How can I disable debug text for KKView ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit these settings in devconfig.lua.:

-- quickly turn on/off the debug labels without having to change the individual flags below
disableAllDebugLabels = YES,

Your attempt should also work but you may have run the code before the view was created and assigned, or before the config settings were loaded.